# div class is not displaying after the specified time

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `div` with the class `rectangle-box` - initially this should be hidden, but then using JavaScript it should appear after a four second delay. However, it's not appearing. Is this due to a mistake in the `getElementsByClassName()` function?

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div class='rectangle-box'>
            <div class='rectangle-content'>
                <div>
                    <span>Hello</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var timePeriodInMs = 4000;
        setTimeout(function() 
            { 
            getElementsByClassName("rectangle-box").style.display = 'block'; 
            } 
            timePeriodInMs);
    </script>

<style>
.rectangle-box{
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #4679BD;
    display: none;
}
.rectangle-box:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 50%;
}
.rectangle-content{
    position:  absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: white;
}
.rectangle-content div {
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
.rectangle-content span {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white
}

</style>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: And you should also get the first element of the returned NodeList for setting the property.

Comment: @Vohuman how can i do that

Comment: You're not using setTimeout properly `timePeriodInMs` should be a variable, and if it is already you need an extra comma before it in the setTimeout call...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` is a method of `document` object. Since it's not a global function you can't call it that way.

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("rectangle-box");
```

Also `getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList`. You should either iterate through the returned list:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(list, function(element) {
    // do something with element
});
```

Or use bracket notation `[index]` or `.item(index)` method for getting a specific wrapped element by index:

```
list[0].style.display = 'block'; 
list.item(0).style.display = 'block';
```

Note that there is also a syntax error in your code, missing `,`.

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    // ... 
}, timePeriodInMs);
```

Answer (score 0):

On the first place getElementsByClassName is not a function and document.getElementsByClassName returns a mode list not a single object use

```
    document.getElementsByClassName("rectangle-box")[0].style.display="block";
```

else

```
          use id in html in element
         <div class='rectangle-content' id='rectangle-content'>   <div><span>hello</span></div></div>
      and use

        document.getElementById("rectangle-box").style.display="block";
```

Comment: Because it's `document.getElementsByClassName`. You didn't mention it.

Comment: @Andy this is by mistake that I forgot to add "document". Is this the appropriate reason to downvote???

Comment: I think so. You're providing an answer that is incorrect. Evidenced by the OP saying that "it's not working bro".

Comment: Than instead of helping someone search all the incorrect answers and downvote them bro!!!

Comment: You still haven't corrected your answer and someone upvoted you, so even if I did drop my downvote you'd have an upvoted answer that was plainly incorrect. Perhaps if you took some time checking your code before jumping in with an answer I would have upvoted you instead.

Comment: @Andy that was just by mistake I forgot to add document object. and afterall we all are humans here!!!

Answer (score 0):

Since you might have more than one element with that class, you need to loop over the nodelist setting the display attribute for each DOM node. (As Vohuman mentions, there's a syntax error in your original code as there should be a comma before `timePeriodInMs` in the `setTimeout` which would have appeared as an error in your console.)

```
setTimeout(function () {
    var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName("rectangle-box");
    for (var i = 0, l = nodes.length; i < l; i++) {
        nodes[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
}, timePeriodInMs);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hjjqoLnd/5/)